# CI multiple image resizing

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing

I'm uplaoding multiple images with CI, they do upload. I am also trying to resize them,
   with the following code, only the first image resizes, rest of them don't.  They get uploaded with their current size.
What's wrong?

Any help'd be really, really appreciated.

```
function doupload() {

    $path = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);

    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value){
        for($n=0; $n<=$count-1; $n++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$n];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$n];   

                $config['upload_path'] = './images';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $path[] = $data['full_path']; //contains full path of every image
        }
    }   

    foreach($path as $p=>$ath){
        $config1 = array(
        'source_image'      => $ath,
        'new_image'         => './images',
        'maintain_ration'   => true,
        'overwrite'         => true, 
        'width'             => 600,
        'height'            => 400
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);            
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->clear();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first load image_lib outside loop you can use initialize in loop and pass new config for every image

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');   

    foreach($path as $p=>$ath){
            $config1 = array(
            'source_image'      => $ath,
            'new_image'         => './images',
            'maintain_ration'   => true,
            'overwrite'         => true, 
            'width'             => 600,
            'height'            => 400
            );

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->image_lib->clear();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter's `Loader` class loads libraries only once, so in your `foreach` you resize the same image multiple times. Move the library loading out of the loop and use the `initialize` method of Image Manipulation library to set the config for every resize.

Answer (score 0):

in my case **load lib in constructor** and use code

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$config['source_image'] = $config['upload_path'].$image_info['file_name'];

$config['new_image'] = $config['upload_path']."thumb_".$image_info['file_name'];
$config['width'] = 313;
$config['height'] = 303;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();

$config['new_image'] = $config['upload_path']."icon_".$image_info['file_name'];
$config['width'] = 70;
$config['height'] = 70;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

keep index name always new_image in `$config['new_image']`